# Add item to an anonymous list

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have a list of anonymous type

```
var myList = db.Products.Select(a => new {a.ProductName, a.ProductId, 
a.Priority}).ToList();
```

And I want to add an other item to this list like

```
myList.Insert(0, new { "--All--", 0, 0}); //Error: Has some invalid arguments
```

I also tried

```
myList.Add(new { "--All--", 0, 0}); //Error: Has some invalid arguments
```

How can I do that?

Edit:

I did this after first answer

```
var packageList = db.Products.Select(a => new { 
         a.ProductName, a.ProductId, a.Priority }).ToList();

packageList.Insert(0, new { ProductName = "All", ProductId = 0, Priority = 0 });
```

but same error again.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should specify property names of anonymous object you create:

```
myList.Insert(0, new { ProductName = "--All--", ProductId = 0, Priority = 0});
```

Keep in mind - you should list **all** properties of anonymous type (names should be same), they should be used in same order, and they should have **exactly same types**. Otherwise object of different anonymous type will be created.

Comment: What types ProductId and Priority have in your Product entity?

Comment: Then all should work fine. Make sure you are using exactly same property names and in same order

Comment: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'

Comment: @liaqatali check my edit - I listed all conditions which matter

Comment: I checked the edit.
Sorry, Does it matter if Priority is of type Int16?

Comment: @Stormenet no, he don't need. Name of property you are using will be used as name of anonymous type property

Comment: @liaqatali yes, that's your problem. You should use `Priority =(short)0`

Comment: Doesn't work if having group linq clause