# How to add item or value in assigned list to var?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I tried many ways but couldn't get the solution.

```
// linq query to getting 3 fields from table
var listData = (from row in db.table
    orderby row.No ascending
    select new {
        row.Id,
        row.No,
        row.Type
    }).ToList();
```

I want to add item or value to listData.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add item to an anonymous list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652006/add-item-to-an-anonymous-list)

Answer (score 0):

try Code:

```
var listData = (from row in db.table

            select new
            {
              Id=  row.Id,
              No=  row.No,
              Type= row.Type
            }
        ).OrderBy(c=>c.No).ToList();
```

Comment: Basically i want to add static value to list, I tried this way but getting error:

listData.Add(new ( Id =  0, No ="-- ALL --", Type = 0 ));

best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generil.List<AnonymousType#1>.Add(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments